# $x^2+xy+y^2$ and $x^2-xy+y^2$ are not both perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $x^2+xy+y^2$ and $x^2-xy+y^2$ cannot be both perfect squares.

Surely $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers. If $x^2+xy+y^2 =a^2$ and $x^2-xy+y^2=b^2$ simultaneously then we have to show that there are no such integers $a$ and $b$.

I have tried that:

Suppose $x^2+xy+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2-xy+y^2=b^2$. Then $2xy=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, so one of $x$ and $y$ is even, but then I am stuck.

Comment: That hyphen before your first polynomial looks a lot like a negative sign.  You should definitely get rid of it.  Also *proove* is not a word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question amounts to showing that the elliptic curve
$Y^2 = X^2+X+1$, $Z^2 = X^2-X+1$
has no rational points other than those with $X=0$ and $X=\infty$.
That can be done by elementary means but requires a Fermat-style descent.
According to Dickson's *History of the Theory of Numbers*
(Volume II, Chapter XVI, bottom of page 481, reference to footnote 119 on p.480),
the result was proved in 1876 by Genocchi.
[In modern language, a Weierstrass form for this curve is
$$y^2 = x^3+x^2-24x+36 = (x-2)(x-3)(x+6),$$
with conductor $48$ and thus in the "Antwerp Tables"
(see [curve 48C](http://modular.math.washington.edu/Tables/antwerp/table1/small_86.jpg)),
where we find that it has Mordell-Weil group
$({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}) \oplus ({\bf Z}/4{\bf Z})$.]

Comment: Can you please provide the descent?

Answer (score 8):

Adding these equations gives $2(x^2+y^2) = a^2 + b^2$; unique factoriation of Gaussian integers shows that we essentially must have $a = x+y$ and $b = x-y$. Now combine this with what you already have.

Comment: What do you mean by "essentially"?  It's certainly not true that $A^2+B^2 = a^2+b^2$ implies that $\{\pm A,\pm B\} = \{\pm a, \pm b\}$.  For example, $8^2+1^2=7^2+4^2$ (and thus $2(8^2+1^2)=11^2+3^2$).

Comment: Note too that your answer suggests that for *any* nonzero $c$
the only $x,y$ for which $x^2+cxy+y^2$ and $x^2-cxy+y^2$
are both squares are those for which $x=0$ or $y=0$.
But that's certainly not true; the first natural number $c$
for which this elliptic curve has positive rank is $c=7$,
and then we can take $(x:y) = (8:1)$, $(1365:176)$,
and infinitely many other ratios.

Answer (score 3):

This is not yet a full answer, but I need to get ready for work now and I'm not sure how to proceed anyway.

This statement clearly doesn't hold if $x$ or $y$ can be $0$, and negative numbers are easily flipped about, so assume that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

If $x$ and $y$ are both even, then dividing each by $2$ will yield another solution. Thus if there is any solution, there must be one for which $x$ or $y$ is odd, so we will assume, without loss of generality, that $y$ is odd.

Since $2xy=(a+b)(a-b)$, either $a+b$ or $a-b$ must be even. But $a+b = (a-b)+2b$, so in fact $a+b$ and $a-b$ are both even.

Thus $4\mid (a+b)(a-b)=2xy$, so $x$ or $y$ is even. Since $y$ is assumed to be odd, $x$ must be even.

Thus $a$ and $b$ are both odd.